# concatenating strings and BigDecimals

Tags: java, string

I need to concatenate a return value with BigDecimal and an int value.

```
int vacationBalance = 5;
///
 public int recordVacation(int vacationBalance) {
    vacationBalance = this.vacationBalance;
    return vacationBalance;
}
////

@Override
public BigDecimal generatePayCheck() {
    wage = getWage() / 26;
    vacationBalance = recordVacation(vacationBalance);
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(wage).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(vacationBalance));
```

Yet I do not need to ADD it, I need to concatenate them. I cannot find it in the docs to do this.
I would like to get the "vacationBalance" in the main method. Is this possible?
Desired result would be:

```
"paycheck balance is X and vacation balance is y."
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define _concatenate_. Do you mean like Strings? Where is that text coming from?

Comment: Then I may be using the wrong terminology. I need generatePayCheck to get me entire wage / 26, got that, but also add the value of vacation along with the same method, which is 5.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: it is actually "adding" the values together, not like a string concatenation like I need.  System.out.println(perm1.getName() + " is a permanent employee who makes an annual wage of " +
                perm1.getWage() + ". Their paycheck this cycle is $" +
                perm1.generatePayCheck());
Output:
"Phil is a permanent employee who makes an annual wage of 100000. Their paycheck this cycle is $3851" <-- I need this to say $3846 and vacation time of 5. I will add the rest once the logic works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requested result, I think you want to return a `String`. And you could use [`String.format(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) to build

> "paycheck balance is X and vacation balance is y."

like

```
public String generatePayCheck() {
    wage = getWage() / 26;
    vacationBalance = recordVacation(vacationBalance);
    return String.format("paycheck balance is %s and "
            + "vacation balance is %s",wage, vacationBalance);
}
```

Comment: I like that you used `String#format` instead of `is " + wage + " and ..." ` :).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `StringBuilder`

```
public String generatePayCheck(){
       wage = getWage() / 26;
       vacationBalance = recordVacation(vacationBalance);
       StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("paycheck balance is ");
       str.append(wage);
       str.append(" and vacation balance is ");
       str.append(vacationBalance);
       str.append(".");

       return str.toString();
}
```

Comment: This is what I was using, but thought I should use BigDecimal since it is a finance type. I figured BigDecimal could separate the two so I can lay it out like a SB. I may just stick with this and not use BD.

Comment: So instead of appending wage you can append wage.toString().

Comment: I believe that is the winner, thanks! I am new to BigDecimal as one can tell.